# accessing and updating values from a controller not linked to database rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a Post model, a posts_controller, and a orders_controller. How can I access and update the Post model from the orders_controller?
Thanks!

Comment: Are these two models related? Do you have a belongs_to or has_many relations between them?

Comment: I do not have a model for the orders_controller. is there anyway I could make them share a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your Post model from the orders_controller just like you are editing any other model.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def some_method
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
       // some action
    else

       // some action
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the params[:id] from the page I just came from?

Comment: because orders/new does not give me a specific id of the post I'm referring to

Comment: You need to pass the specific post to the path some_method_path(@post). I am assuming the page you are coming from lists all the posts using @posts.each, and inside that block you can have the some_method_path(@post).